# Obtain lowest power of two with a given leading digit

Tags: haskell, math

I have to define `lowestPower` such that

```
lowestPower           :: Integer -> (Integer,Integer)
```

`lowestPower n` is the pair `(k, m)` where `m` is the lowest power of 2 whose decimal representation begins with the digit `n` and `k` is its exponent (i. e. `2^k = m`). For example,

```
 lowestPower 3             ==  (5,32)
 lowestPower 7             ==  (46,70368744177664)
 fst (lowestPower 982)     ==  3973
```

I have tried this:

```
lowestPower :: Integer -> (Integer,Integer)
lowestPower n = (k,m)
  where
    k <- [0..]
    (head . cifras) m = n
    2^k = m

cifras :: Integer -> [Integer]
cifras n = [read[d] | d <- show n]
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I think that it is obvious

Comment: @aprendiendo-a-programar No, you just said what you want to achieve in the end and appended a code dump; You didn't actually say what your problem was.

Answer (score 2):

`k <- [0..]` is not something you can write in a `where` block. `where` blocks just *define* stuff, possibly depending on parameters from the enclosing scope, but they can't handle such “looping constructs”. Nor can you use equations as conditionals there, such as `(head . cifras) m = n`. Both of this would be more like *logic programming*, but Haskell is functional instead, i.e. it doesn't solve propositions but simply assigns functional equations. I.e. all `=` lines must be of the form

```
newVariableOrFunction 〘..arguments..〙 = some expression that can be computed
```

You can write something looking very similar to your original code though by using a *list comprehension*, i.e. you basically quantify explicitly over all the conceivable values. Like

```
lowestPower n = head
  [ (k,m)
  | k <- [0..]
  , let m = 2^k
  , (head . cifras) m == n
  ]
```

Since that list comprehension is basically just a way of implementing a loop, it's somewhat more natural to just define the function by recursion though.